# Celerra: zoning done to data mover

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, celerra

I have a small confusion-while zoning to data mover, wwn zoning in preferred. Which should be Node 50060160c1e10d7d -please correct me if I am wrong.

Because in my environment I see it is zoned to SP and Port 5006016041e10d7d

DM output-

> FCP HBA 0: N_PORT S_ID 018100 Node 50060160c1e10d7d Port
>   5006016041e10d7d

complete output: When I run the command to get the WWNs of the DMs server_2 and server_3 -(2 DMs)

```
FCP HBA 0: N_PORT S_ID 018100 Node 50060160c1e10d7d Port 5006016041e10d7d
FCP HBA 1: N_PORT S_ID 018100 Node 50060160c1e10d7d Port 5006016141e10d7d
FCP HBA 2: OFFLINE ALPA 000001 Node 50060160c1e10d7d Port 5006016241e10d7d
FCP HBA 3: OFFLINE ALPA 000001 Node 50060160c1e10d7d Port 5006016341e10d7d
```

Comment: what *exactly* is your problem or question?

Comment: to zone DM to array- which wwn i need to select from this output?       FCP HBA 0: N_PORT S_ID 018100 Node 50060160c1e10d7d Port 5006016041e10d7d   (  Node 50060160c1e10d7d  or Port 5006016041e10d7d)

Comment: I'd say it's the Port wwn. Btw, what command are you running to generate this info?